# How to make calling code agnostic of implicit parameter passed under the hood?

Tags: scala, implicits

I want to be able to surround a block of code with a transaction. The calling code should be as simple as this:

```
transactional {
  save("something")
}
```

I thought to make the `transactional` function like this:

```
def transactional(block: => Unit): Unit = {
  implicit val conn: Connection = ???

  conn.begin()
  try {
    block
    conn.commit()
  } catch {
    case ex: Exception =>
      conn.rollback()
      throw ex
  } finally {
    conn.close()
  }
}
```

Now the `save` method will need to do something with the Connection, but I want to make the calling code agnostic of that (see above). I naively implemented it like this:

```
def save(operation: String)(implicit conn: Connection): Unit = {
  println(s"saving $operation using $conn")
}
```

Of course I get a compilation error, that the Connection can not be found. What part am I missing to wire the Connection from the `transactional` function to the `save` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `transactional` function something like below (look at the code snippet of transactional). The problem here is connection is available with transactional but it has to reach save function implicitly. So once you get the connection object hand it to the a function which runs inside the transaction and then this code (f) can get access to the connection. Once f gets access to the connection we can make it `implicit` using the implicit keyword. Now functions like save which take connection implicitly can seamlessly be called inside the transactional.

Important changes to transactional

1) Instead of passing the code block (block: => Unit) pass f (f: Connection => Unit)

2) Inside transactional apply f to connection object and give f access to the connection object.

```
def transactional(f: Connection => Unit): Unit = {
  val conn = getConnectionFromDatabase()
  conn.begin()
  try {
    f(conn)
    conn.commit()
  } catch {
    case ex: Exception =>
      conn.rollback()
      throw ex
  } finally {
    conn.close()
  }
}
```

Now you can use it like this

```
transactional { implicit conn =>
  save("something")
}
```

if you save function is like this

```
def save(str: String): Connection => Unit = ???
```

Then you can go without connection

```
transactional(save("foo"))
```

Comment: Thank you, the modified version allows me to leave the connection out of the calling code. It also improves on the answer by Tzach Zohar in that I can still wrap code around the save function, and it will still work. I will accept this answer for that reason. If wrapping is not needed, his answer is slightly simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without using `implicit`, and without changing the calling code, if `save` *returns* a function expecting a Connection:

```
def transactional(block: Connection => Unit): Unit = {
  val conn: Connection = ???

  // stuff..
  block(conn)
  // stuff..
}

def save(operation: String): Connection => Unit = { conn =>
  println(s"saving $operation using $conn")
}

transactional {
  save("something")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Now I have one more question. If I replace `save("something")` with `for (i <- 1 to 3) { save("something") }`, it doesn't work. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Jeroen, in the code above `transactional` expects an argument of type `Connection => Unit`. save() returns exactly that, the `for` loop does not.